# Not able to receive response from express code shows undefined in console

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

My post request works fine but the response from node/express is not accessible I have tried to log console the response but there is no body or data. Can you tell me what am i doing wrong. FYI this is just a demo project to learn MERN stack

Login.js

```
 function myFunc(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      fetch("http://localhost:5000/login", {
          method: "POST",
          headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
          },
          body: JSON.stringify({ firstname: name, pass }),
      }).then((response) => {
          console.log(response);
      });
 }
```

express code

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    var msg = " ";
    User.find({firstname: req.body.firstname }, "password", function (err, result) {
        if (result > 0) {
            if (result[0].password === req.body.pass) {
                msg = "Login Successfull";
            } else {
                msg = "Username and/or Password worng!!";
            }
        } else msg = "no user found";
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
    console.log(msg);
    res.send({ msg });
});
```

server.js

```
const app = express();
 app.use(cors());
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

 app.use("/signUp", user);
 app.use("/login", login);
```

Comment: Do you have proper middleware installed to read the body, parse it and populate `req.body`?  If not, `req.body` will be empty as nothing has actually read the request body and parsed it.  In this case, since the request is JSON, you would need `app.use(express.json())` before the request handler where you want to use `req.body`.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes I do have proper middleware installed I am using app.use(express.json()) in a server.js file and then router for post request and also my msg variable does not change either I just did not add the code for server.js

Answer (score 1):

You have `res.send({msg})` in the wrong place.  Your server is executing that line of code BEFORE you have assigned a value to `msg`.  Instead, move the `res.send()` inside the asynchronous callback:

```
router.post("/", (req, res) => {
    User.find({firstname: req.body.firstname }, "password", function (err, result) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            res.sendStatus(500);
            return;
        }
        let msg;
        if (result.length > 0) {
            if (result[0].password === req.body.pass) {
                msg = "Login Successfull";
            } else {
                msg = "Username and/or Password worng!!";
            }
        } else {
            msg = "no user found";
        }
        console.log(msg);
        res.send({msg});
    });
});
```

Also, note that I changed to `if (result.length > 0)` since I think you were trying to test if the result array has values in it.

Also, your error handling was incorrect.  You either use a plain callback to `User.find()` OR you don't pass a callback and you use the promise it returns.  You were trying to do a mix of the two which will not work as `User.find()` either accepts a plain callback or returns a promise, not both.